# How to obtain the output after parsing the csv using csv-parser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, output, node-csv-parse

I am parsing a huge csv (1.2GB) using csvparser and trying to obtain certain column data from the parsed csv. I am trying to push the data to the array after processing, but only getting empty array as output. How can I fix this code?

```
var parse = require('csv-parse');

var output = []
var parser = parse({
   delimiter: '\t',
   columns: true
}, function(err, csvLine) {
   for (var l = 0; l < csvLine.length; l++) {
      output.push(csvLine[l].id)
   }
});

console.log(output)

fs.createReadStream('file.csv', {
   encoding: 'utf8'
}).pipe(parser);
```

The output at `console.log(output)` is always an empty array. Please help me solve this.

I tried to understand the post here - [Save csv-parse output to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013578/save-csv-parse-output-to-a-variable). But I was not able to understand and fix the code.

Comment: That looks asynchronous. Try moving `console.log(output)` inside the `function(err, csvLine){}` right after the `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because of asynchronous.** The line *console.log(output)* runs after the declaration of parser variable. At that time **output variable** has no values in it.

You have to access **output variable** after the loop when all data read from csv as given below.

```js
    var parse = require('csv-parse');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var output = []
    var parser = parse({
       delimiter: ',',
       columns: true
    }, function(err, csvLine) {
       for (var l = 0; l < csvLine.length; l++) {
          output.push(csvLine[l].visitortype)
       }
       console.log(output)
    }); 
    fs.createReadStream('file.csv', {
       encoding: 'utf8'
    }).pipe(parser);
```

Comment: Thank you @mukesh. This worked. The console.log()  should be always at the function level. Is it the same when we read multiple files too?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fast-csv` to parse the file as `ReadableStream`, then use async iteration (`for await`) to process it line by line. It's simpler.

```
const csv = require("fast-csv")

let myList=[];

const csvStream = csv.fromPath(filename);
for await(const row of csvStream) {
    myList.push(row[1]); // get the second column
}
```